# Action Hook With $this Inside a Class in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a hook based in 'display_attached_media' inside the class Sensei_Media_Attachments in the plugin **Sensei LMS Media Attachments** to active it in a custom location using in my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'custom_action', array( $this, 'display_attached_media' ), 35 );
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Plugin sample:

```
class Sensei_Media_Attachments {

    private static $instance = null;
    private $assets_dir;
    private $assets_url;
    private $token;

public function frontend_hooks() {
    // Media files display.
    add_action( 'sensei_single_lesson_content_inside_after', array( $this, 'display_attached_media' ), 35 );
    add_action( 'sensei_single_course_content_inside_before', array( $this, 'display_attached_media' ), 35 );
} }
```

When used within the class, it worked fine, but I don't want to edit the plugin files.

---

**Update**

When i followed the suggestion of @disinfor the `Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context` changed from *functions.php* to *class-sensei-media-attachments.php.php* on line 226, so I made some research and found the problem. Inside the function display_attached_media I have a call based on `$this`, so I replaced it with `self::` and everything worked well.

But, does anyone know if we have another to fix it, instead change the plugin code?

Comment: Change `$this` to `'Sensei_Media_Attachements'` - $this refers to the Class internally. Since you want to call it outside, you need to pass the actual Class name (passed as a string - so make sure you put the single quotes around it).

Comment: Thanks @disinfor , I'm getting now the following error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in`

Comment: Can you post more of what the plugin has in it's class with the action filters? Also, post more of what you've tried (not in the plugin, but in functions.php or wherever you're putting the code)

Comment: Hi @disinfor, here are the complete class: https://github.com/woocommerce/sensei-media-attachments/blob/master/classes/class-sensei-media-attachments.php.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It seems you are going about this the wrong way. `display_attached_media` is hooked into `sensei_single_lesson_content_inside_after` and `sensei_single_course_content_inside_before`. Meaning that method runs on that hook. If you want to create  your own hook, you need to use `do_action( 'custom_hook', array( 'Sensei_Media_Attachements', 'display_attached_media' ) )`. That will use the `display_attached_media` wherever you put it. If you want to alter what is output from `display_attached_media` you need to use the available `filters` in that method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use $this outside the class. Please call the action as

```
add_action( 'custom_action', 'display_attached_media', 35 );
```

in your theme's functions.php

Comment: Thanks Neelesh, I tried it and get the error:

Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'display_attached_media' not found or invalid function name in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287

Comment: I think that the function display_attached_media is private or protected. Try extending the class Sensei_Media_Attachments and try like above using $this if the method is protected.

Comment: Hi Neelesh, the `function display_attached_media` is defined as `public`, but when I followed your sugestion with the code below:

`class NewSenseiMedia extends Sensei_Media_Attachments {
  public function showMedia() {
    add_action( 'customaction', array( 'Sensei_Media_Attachments', 'display_attached_media' ), 35 );
  }
}

$NewSenseiMedia = new NewSenseiMedia();
$NewSenseiMedia-> showMedia();` 

I got the following error: 
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to private Sensei_Media_Attachments::__construct() from invalid context `

Comment: Can you provide the entire class file?